# Forcing terminal theme based on environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I have a setup on my ubuntu where I can setup different environments for different purposes, essentially ending up having a bunch of ~/.bash_env_... in my home directory.

Example:

```
~/.bash_env_1
~/.bash_env_2
~/.bash_env_3
~/.bash_env_4
```

I already set the terminal prompt to tell me which environment I am at.

Is it possible to also force the terminal to change theme depending on the env?
E.g. when I run source ~/.bash_env_1 I would like the terminal where I run this to change to "some theme", essentially changing the whole palette.

I could not find anything about this specific topic, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, just put your theme changing code in ~/.bash_env_1 so it executes when you source the file.

Comment: Do you know where I can find how that code looks like?